# How do I detect if shift is held while pressing "7" to make division

Tags: python, keyboard, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator, but I keep running into the same issue.

Every time I press 7 it runs the function "sevenCmd" but also "divisionCmd" even tho I'm not holding shift.

I am using the "keyboard" module

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('+', lambda: plusCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('-', lambda: minusCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('*', lambda: timesCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('/', lambda: divisionCmd()) #Problems on this line
keyboard.add_hotkey('Enter', lambda: equalsCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('C', lambda: clearCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey(',', lambda: commaCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('.', lambda: commaCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('Backspace', lambda: deleteCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('1', lambda: oneCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('2', lambda: twoCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('3', lambda: threeCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('4', lambda: fourCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('5', lambda: fiveCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('6', lambda: sixCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('7', lambda: sevenCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('8', lambda: eightCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('9', lambda: nineCmd())
keyboard.add_hotkey('0', lambda: zeroCmd())
```

Comment: trying to run it on linux (with sudo) says "ValueError: Key 'C' is not mapped to any known key."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in some logic in the `division` hotkey to check whether or not shift is pressed

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('7 + shift', lambda: divisionCmd()) #Problems on this line
```

this works

Comment: I did try that if you’re talking about using (‘Shift’ and ‘/‘) but that didn’t work, can you explain further?

Comment: When you have the '/' hotkey, instead check for ('shift'+'7')